# SQL Trigger Update After Insert

Tags: t-sql, triggers

I am trying to create a trigger that will add a calculated field to one field after insertion.  I've been playing around with this for days and could use another set of eyes.  Basically, if the field PolicyNum is empty and a couple other parameters are met, the trigger will fire, inserted my function as well as a couple of housekeeping items.

```
ALTER TRIGGER PolicyNumber ON Consolidated 

AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT i.PolicyNum, i.PlanCode
    FROM Inserted AS i
    JOIN Consolidated as C
    ON c.ID = i.ID and c.SEQN = i.SEQN
    WHERE C.PolicyNum = '' AND
    C.PlanCode like '%NYL%'
    )

DECLARE @PolicyNumber nVarChar(255)
DECLARE @IMISID nVarChar(10)
DECLARE @SEQID Int

EXEC    @PolicyNumber = [dbo].[fn_GetNYLPolicyNumber]

--Updating Record
UPDATE Consolidated
SET PolicyNum = @PolicyNumber, 
UpdatedBy = 'Trigger', 
UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE (ID = @IMISID) AND (SEQN = @SEQID)
END
```

Comment: You need a BEGIN and corresponding END for your IF statement. Without that, I'm guessing the UPDATE is always firing and you don't want it to be? Or it might be erroring out? What results are you currently getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
ALTER TRIGGER PolicyNumber ON Consolidated 

AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
IF EXISTS (SELECT i.PolicyNum, i.PlanCode
    FROM Inserted AS i
    JOIN Consolidated as C
    ON c.ID = i.ID and c.SEQN = i.SEQN
    WHERE C.PolicyNum = '' AND
    C.PlanCode like '%NYL%'
    )
begin
DECLARE @PolicyNumber nVarChar(255)
DECLARE @IMISID nVarChar(10)
DECLARE @SEQID Int

EXEC    @PolicyNumber = [dbo].[fn_GetNYLPolicyNumber]

--Updating Record
UPDATE Consolidated
SET PolicyNum = @PolicyNumber, 
UpdatedBy = 'Trigger', 
UpdatedDate = GETDATE()
WHERE (ID = @IMISID) AND (SEQN = @SEQID)
END
end
```